# Send email via Stored Procedure Fails

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

```
DECLARE 
    @id nvarchar(MAX),
    @Counter int,
    @CheckCount int

DECLARE CC1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT Ename, Ecount
    FROM TestDB.dbo.TestEmail

OPEN CC1

FETCH NEXT FROM CC1 INTO @id, @Counter

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    Begin
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
         @profile_name = 'Bob',
         @recipients = @id,
         @body = 'The stored procedure finished successfully. #$%',
         @subject = 'Automated Success Message' ;

    update TestDB.dbo.TestEmail 
    set Ecount = Ecount + 1 
    where Ename = @id 

    print @id
END

Select 
    @CheckCount = Ecount 
from TestDB.dbo.TestEmail 
where Ename = @id

print @CheckCount

If @CheckCount > 3
Begin
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = N'6a81d6b3-af2d-4a27-b688-b9c69098f840', @enabled = 0
    return
    PRINT 'Count reached 3+'
End 

FETCH NEXT FROM CC1 INTO @id, @Counter
END

CLOSE CC1
DEALLOCATE CC1
```

I have a table `TestEmail` with two columns `Ename, Ecount`. By using this table, I am trying to send emails to users. If the `Ecount` is greater than 3, the scripts exits, and nothing happens.

One user will receive emails for three times only. But my functionality fails, can't figure out where I am going wrong. My script doesn't throw any error but doesn't work either.

Comment: Here's a clue - What do you think the [return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms174998.aspx) does? I think marc's edit makes it very clear...

Comment: the return immediately  exits everything.

Comment: Now it's working. :) I will be grateful to you, if you give  some more hints regarding exiting this script when user email counts is greater than three. I am thankful to Marc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc's edit worked for me. The time I wrote the question, I had  no idea about TSQL programming. 
Although, the code in my question is working fine, Here is a wonderful tutorial to send an email via SQl server.

[Send email in SQL server](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/sql.aspx)